# Get current case number

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a simple switch case statement, and I want to get the current case int.

For example:

```
case 5:

// some code

break;
```

I want to get the 5.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually to get inside a switch case you need to meet a condition. What you can do is print the condition variable inside the switch case.

```
int conditionVariable = 0;
```

At some point in execution the `conditionVariable` will be set to a value by something in your program. Then the switch case will execute, which will compare `conditionVariable` to your `cases`.

```
switch (conditionVariable) 
{      
    case 5:
       // This prints the case number to the logcat.
       Log.d("tag", conditionVariable);
       break;
   . . .
}
```

Comment: I would like some relevant links or an example. thanks.

Comment: @Max what more example would you like? I just wrote the code that would print the value for you.

Comment: Just saw it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

scan your keyboard input 
store it in int varialble

```
int currentcase;

switch(currentcase)
{


case 5:
 System.out.println("u r in "+ currentcase)

break;
}
```